# When I pass the Node variable that is "top" inside the node objects ? does it help it to point the previous data?

Tags: java, class

I am writing a code to practice some linked list example with basics but came across a problem when in linked list class in voidadd method what does it means when I pass the Node variable that is "top" inside the node objects ? does it help it to point the previous data? i have indicated the part that refers to my question

```
public class Node
{
    private int data;
    private Node nextNode;

    public Node(int dataP , Node nextNodeP)
    {
        data = dataP;nextNode = nextNodeP;
    }

    public int getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public Node getNextNode()
    {
        return nextNode;
    }

    public void setData(int newData) //to replace the value of some notes [12| ] --> [120| ]
    {
        data = newData;
    }


    public void setNext(Node newNextNode)  //  pointing to  top ---> [120| ] ---> [last | null]
    {
        nextNode = newNextNode;
    }
 }

 public class LinkedList {
     private Node top;
     private int size;

     public LinkedList() {
         top = null;
         size = 0;
     }

     public int getSize() {
        return size;
     }

     public void addNode(int newData) {
        Node temp = new Node(newData, top); //question 
        top = temp; //points to the same
        size++;
     }
}
```

Comment: Typically you have `private Node parent;`  so each node has a reference to its parent, rather then to the top node.

Comment: so the new Node temp is formed and it is given the reference and then afterward it simply transfers the reference and at the end all points to parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a node at its own class. 
Here is a simple example :

```
public class LinkedList {

    private Node first,last;
    private int size ;

    //adds node as last. not null safe
    public void addNode(Node node) {

        if(first == null) {
            node.setParent(null);
            first = node;
            last = node;
        }else {
            node.setParent(last);
            last = node;
        }

        size++;
    }

    public Node getFirst() {return first;}
    public Node getLast() { return last;    }
    public int getSize() {return size;}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        list.addNode(new Node(0,null));
        list.addNode(new Node(1,null));
        list.addNode(new Node(2,null));
        list.addNode(new Node(3,null));

        Node node = list.getLast();
        System.out.println("list has "+ list.size + " nodes:");
        while(node != null) {
            System.out.println(node);
            node = node.getParent();
        }
    }
}

class Node{

    private int data;
    private Node parent;
    Node(int nodeData, Node parent) {
        data = nodeData;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public int getData() {  return data;}
    public void setData(int data) { this.data = data; }
    public Node getParent() {return parent; }
    public void setParent(Node parent) {this.parent = parent;}
    @Override
    public String toString() {return "Node "+getData() +" parent:"+ getParent();}
}
```